# Recommended for admission by the department but still haven't received official decision

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics

I was recommended for admission into the Math PhD program at a large state university in the US two weeks ago and the department informed me that they are forwarding my application to be reviewed by the graduate school. The graduate school said they will review my application and will get back to me in two weeks for official decision. Two weeks have passed and I still haven't received any notification from them, so I sent a polite email asking about my status couple days ago. But at this point, I still haven't got any update.

What should I do now? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Polite phone call to the graduate school.  Emails could very well be received initially by students, and given that many schools are on spring break right now, that could delay them (or just student workers losing an e-mail wouldn't be unheard of).

If the phone call isn't able to resolve any doubts, speak with the department you applied to and they can put some pressure on the graduate school.

Comment: I agree.  Be polite is key!